# Inject view to other class in Android

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-annotations, dagger

I'm using in my project AndroidAnnotations and Dagger.

I would like to inject View (injected to Activity via AndroidAnnotations) into other class via Dagger.

Now I have this code, but I would like to obtain `ActionBarDrawerToggle` with `@Injection`:

```
// MainActivity.java
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_main)
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @ViewById
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    ActionBarDrawerToggle mMainDrawerToggle;

    @AfterInject
    void daggerInject() {
        application.inject(this);
    }

    @AfterViews
    void setupViews() {
        mMainDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                drawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_main_drawer,
                R.string.main_drawer_open,
                R.string.main_drawer_close);
    }
}
```

I've made something like this, but it doesn't work because Dagger don't know how to get DrawerLayout object.

```
// ApplicationModule.java
@Module(
        library = true,
        injects = MainActivity_.class
)
public class ApplicationModule {

    private final MyApp application;

    public ApplicationModule(MyApp application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    ActionBarDrawerToggle provideActionBarDrawerToggle(DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                application,
                drawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_main_drawer,
                R.string.main_drawer_open,
                R.string.main_drawer_close);
    }
}
```

How can I make that `ActionBarDrawerToggle` will be injected by Dagger?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like a true dependency for the Activity itself - The Activity is the one creating the DrawerLayout from it's own view.

If really had to do it, you can have create a custom ActivityModule that takes in the DrawerLayout or Activity dependency in it's constructor. This would let you share it fragments and children views.

```
@Module(...)
public class ActivityModule {

  private final Activity activity;

  public ActivityModule(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
  }

  @Provides
  ActionBarDrawerToggle provideActionBarDrawerToggle() {
    //create the toggle and return it here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the game, but the problem is you are missing the `@Inject` annotation before `ActionBarDrawerToggle mMainDrawerToggle;`

Answer (score 0):

First thing you're going to need is an activity module and an activity component [here's how](http://frogermcs.github.io/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2-custom-scopes/), unless you only have a single activity.  Next, you need to instantiate the toggle prior to doing the dagger injection.  If that works for you then:

Create a getter for the view in your activity. then in your module:

```
@Provides @Singleton
  ActionBarDrawerToggle provideActionBarDrawerToggle() {
    activity.getActionBarDrawerToggle()
  }
```

now you can inject the actionBarToggle,

```
 @Inject ActionBarToggle toggle;
```